# iOS - swipe UICollectionViewCell horizontally

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, swipe

I have a UICollectionView that looks like a tableView and I want the cells to swipe only horizontally.

I have managed to make them to move around, but the problem is I can move them up as well and basically I can move them in any direction and I want them to swipe like a tableViewCell when you delete it for example.

In the end I want to be able to just swipe a cell out of the screen horizontally

I have attached a image of how the collection view looks now and a cell that moves around(the red one)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a way to do it with `UIPanGestureRecognizer` after all. All the operations are on the cell(inside the cell class). Below you have the solution that worked for me

```
var swipeGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer!
var originalPoint: CGPoint!

func configureCell() {
    setupSwipeGesture()
}

func setupSwipeGesture() {
        swipeGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(swiped(_:)))
        swipeGesture.delegate = self

        self.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGesture)
    }


func swiped(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
let xDistance:CGFloat = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self).x

        switch(gestureRecognizer.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerState.began:
            self.originalPoint = self.center
        case UIGestureRecognizerState.changed:
            let translation: CGPoint = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self)
            let displacement: CGPoint = CGPoint.init(x: translation.x, y: translation.y)

            if displacement.x + self.originalPoint.x < self.originalPoint.x {
                self.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(translationX: displacement.x, y: 0)
                self.center = CGPoint(x: self.originalPoint.x + xDistance, y: self.originalPoint.y)
            }
        case UIGestureRecognizerState.ended:
            let hasMovedToFarLeft = self.frame.maxX < UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2
            if (hasMovedToFarLeft) {
                removeViewFromParentWithAnimation()
            } else {
                resetViewPositionAndTransformations()
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }

func resetViewPositionAndTransformations(){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(), animations: {
            self.center = self.originalPoint
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 0)
        }, completion: {success in })
    }

func removeViewFromParentWithAnimation() {
        var animations:(()->Void)!
        animations = {self.center.x = -self.frame.width}

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: animations , completion: {success in self.removeFromSuperview()})
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to do a few things:

1) Add a [`UISwipeGestureRecognizer`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiswipegesturerecognizer) to each cell. Be sure to set `direction = .left`.

2) Add the target for the gesture recognizer, and make sure the target can communicate with the collection view's layout. 2a) The collection view data source could add the target in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`. You would need a way to make sure it's not added repeatedly on reused cells. 2b) You could add the gesture recognizer from within the cell, and create a delegate relationship with your view controller.

3) You will need the index path of the cell that was swiped. To get the cell from the gesture recognizer (2a) call it's [`view`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624212-view) property and cast as UICollectionViewCell. If you use a delegate (2b) or another method, it should pass the cell back. Then you can call `collectionView.cellForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell?` to get the index path.

4) Call `deleteItemAtIndexPath:` on the collection view, in `performBatchUpdates` etc.

5) It seems the simplist way to animate the disappearance to the left (disclaimer, I haven't done this part myself though I've worked with attributes) is to implement [finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617740-finallayoutattributesfordisappea?language=objc) in a subclass of UICollectionViewLayout.

First, you will need the attributes cached. So override and cache:

```
class LeftDisappearLayout : UICollectionViewFLowLayout {

    var cachedAttributes = [NSIndexPath:UICollectionViewAttributes?]()

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath) 
        cachedAttributes[indexPath] = attributes
        return attributes
    }
```

Then since iOS 9 it appears there's a simple way to have the system animate to the left for you:

```
    func finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItem(at itemIndexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        if var attributes = cachedAttributes[indexPath] {
            let newCenterX : CGFloat = -1 * (attributes.frame.size.width / 2)  
            attributes.center = CGPoint(newCenterX, attributes.center.y)
            return attributes 
        }
        AssertionFailure("Unable to find cached attributes!") // Saying, "This should never happen and in development crash to alert the developer, but in production gracefully revert to default."
        return nil
    }
}
```

Make sure to set your collection view to use this layout. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Mike! I found a way to do it exactly the way I wanted using UIPanGestureRecognizer, but thanks for the answer.